# How to call construction on another inherited class in c++?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a constructor using inheritance.

Why does mammal class not inherit the animal constructor ?

Also, why can't I overload it ?

**PS:** constructor takes 4 parameters.

Here is my code :

```cpp
class animal {

    public:
        string name;
        string diet;
        float dailycalories;
        float expectedlifetime;

    virtual void display() {

    }

    virtual void calculateExpectedLifeTime() {

    }

    animal(string nam, string dit, float dacalo, float explife) {
        expectedlifetime = 0;
        nam = name;
        dit = dailycalories;
        dacalo = dailycalories;
        explife = expectedlifetime;
    }
};

class mammal: public animal {

    animal(string nam, string dit, float dacalo, float explife) {

    }

    public:
        float brainsize;
};
```

Comment: You are trying to define a constructor named `animal` in a class named `mammal`. The constructor should be named after its class.

Comment: Did the change but got an error saying "no matching function for call to animal::animal()

it says..

Comment: You may wish to read about a "constructor initializer list" in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Inside `animal` class, you'll need to provide a default constructor for `animal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you call the parent constructor in the child constructor in C++:

```
class mammal: public animal{
        mammal(string name, string dit, float dacalo,float explife, float brainsize):animal(name, dit, dacalo, explife){
          this -> brainsize = brainsize;
        }

    public:
        float brainsize;
};
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: @milliar if it worked click the checkmark next to the answer

Comment: Welcome to SO @milliar